# Dark terrain graphics in Civilization V: God and Kings

Tags: civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I downloaded Gods and Kings yesterday and everything runs fine, no glitches whatsoever. But there's one thing that's weird or odd about it. I see a lot of YouTube videos and screenshots and it's all normal as well. But the terrain coloring is different compared to mine and the ones I've seen in the screenshots and YouTube videos. The terrain is oddly dark, like the grass is supposed to be green but its very dark dark green, even the sand is very dark.

When I say dark, it's not the low-brightness-setting dark, because it's on high. It seems to be the terrain and models as well. The leader videos are all normal. I have screenshots of this problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot didn't work, can you edit your question to try and add it? Or at least just provide the link and someone else will embed it for you.

Comment: @Oak Both of the screenshots in the link worked for me. o.o; It's odd, the wheat tile looks normal but the underlying plains UNDER the wheat is almost like it's washed out. Have you, by chance, tried verifying your game cache/uninstalling and reinstalling yet?

Comment: i reinstalled steam and civ5 all together, whats wierd is that it wasnt like this before the gods and kings dl. verifying game cache? sorry im not so smart :(

Comment: It seems like im the only one with this problem :(

Comment: @JamesCho To verify your game's cache, when you have opened your Steam library, right click on "Sid Meyer's Civilization V", and click Properties. In the menu that comes up, click the Local Files tab, then click "Verify Integrity of Game Cache". This will check all local game files for the game and, if any are corrupted, replace them with non-corrupted ones. Have you also tried launching the game with Gods And Kings disabled through the DLC menu in the main menu of Civ V?

Comment: @Rilgon Arcsinh im james cho, signed in with my steam account, yea theres nothing wrong with the cache. I unchecked the gods and kings in the dlc section in the main menu of the game then exited. restarted the game, but it automatically resets it to gods and kings. I updated my graphics driver and stuff. Theres seems to be no solution, unless i can totally wipe gods and kings out and reinstall that by istelf which is hard to do in steam or even if its possible

Comment: i tried verifying cache again, it says "1 files failed to validate and will be recquired"  ?? what does that even mean and how can i fix it. Its odd that ive been doing this over and over and i didnt get this messege beofre

Comment: That infers that there were, in fact, problematic files, and Steam will re-download and correct them. In the future, though, make sure you log in with the same account you logged in to submit the question - you can *always* add comments to your own questions or answers even if you don't have the reputation necessary to add them to others'.

Comment: lol sorry, steam will redownload them?? when? ive been waiting all day. :(

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If the redownload does not fix the problem, you could look at the following:

Have you tried changing the graphics settings (not brightness but detail levels)?

What graphics card (GPU) do you have and which driver version did you update to? Have you tried other driver versions (stable or beta)? At least Nvidia's latest beta drivers mention a compatibility fix:

"Fixed a compatibility issue with Civilization V and GeForce 400/500 series GPUs"
http://www.nvidia.com/object/win8-win7-winvista-64bit-304.79-beta-driver.html

Depending on your GPU, you could also try looking at the settings provided with the manufacturer's control panel software. They may sometimes override game settings.